# Stability and Asymptotical behavior of a nonlinear system

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, mathematical-biology, epidemiology

A simple mathematical model to describe how the HIV/AIDS virus infects healthy cells is given by the following equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dT}{dt} &= s - dT - \beta Tv \\
\frac{dT^*}{dt} &= \beta Tv - \mu T^* \\
\frac{dv}{dt} &= kT^* - cv
\end{align}
$$

I have found two equilibrium points (DFE and EE), given by

$$
(T_0, T_0^*, v_0) = \left(\frac{s}{d}, 0, 0\right)
$$

and

$$
(T_0, T_0^*, v_0) = \left(\frac{c\mu}{\beta k}, \frac{s}{\mu} - \frac{cd}{\beta k}, \frac{sk}{c\mu} - \frac{d}{\beta}\right)=\left(\frac{c\mu}{\beta k}, (R_0-1)\frac{dc}{\beta k},(R_0-1)\frac{d}{\beta} \right)
$$
Where $R_0$ is the basic reproduction number.

I am asked to discuss

- the **stability of these equilibria** and
- the **asymptotical behavior** of this system

However, I am wondering how to do that because the system is not linear, and I typically use the Jacobian matrix <del>(the only method I am aware of)</del>, linearizing method to determine stability. Any solution or hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very well-studied system for within-host viral infection. The global stability (for an even more general system) is provided in https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036139902406905. The compound matrix approach used there is technically very similar to the Lyapunov approach.

Answer (score 0):

The system as a whole isn't linear; but the local stability of each equilibrium should be determined by the linearization of the system of equations around that point.  In general, for any fixed point $(T_0, T^*_0, v_0)$, you can write $T=T_0+\delta T$, $T^*=T^*_0+\delta T^*$, $v=v_0+\delta v$, and then expand the system of equations to linear order in the $\delta$-variables:
$$
\dot{\delta T}=\dot{T}=s-d(T_0+\delta T)-\beta(T_0+\delta T)(v_0+\delta v)\approx -(d + \beta v_0)\delta T-\beta T_0\delta v \\
\dot{\delta T^*}=\dot{T^*}=\beta(T_0+\delta T)(v_0+\delta v)-\mu(T_0^*+\delta T^*)\approx\beta v_0 \delta T+\beta T_0 \delta v-\mu \delta T^* \\
\dot{\delta v}=\dot{v}=k(T_0^*+\delta T^*)-c(v_0+\delta v) = k\delta T^{*}-c\delta v.
$$
Substituting the values from each fixed point lets you write these (linear) equations purely in terms of the free parameters $(d,c,k,s,\mu,\beta)$, and the Jacobian matrix will tell you the local stability.  How far does that get you?

Comment: "*the Jacobian matrix will tell you the local stability*" this is not always true. In some cases, the linearization method is inconclusive.

Comment: Of course, that’s true in cases of marginal stability.  Is that the case here?  OP’s work shown in the question doesn’t yet get that far.

Comment: As the coefficients have not yet been specified, some values could turn the case in this direction.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am going through my exams. I will update my work later. But thanks for your response @mjqxxxx