# Stability of normal state in chemostat model

Tags: stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, population-dynamics

The chemostat model proposed by monod was given by,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=[K(c)-D]x\\
\frac{dc}{dt}&=D[c_0-c]-\frac1yK(c)x
\end{align}
$$
where $x(t)$ is the population of micro-organisms and $c(t)$ is the concentration of the nutrient, And $K(c)=\frac{Kc}{K+c},y$ and $D$ are growth rate, constant proportionality for consumption of nutrient by micro-organisms and the dilution rate. I got the steady states,

$$
\begin{align}
\bar{x}=0,\bar{c}=c_0\text{ (washout state)}\\
K(\bar c)=D,\bar x=y(c_0-\bar c)\text{ (normal state)}
\end{align}\tag1
$$

I check the stability of washout state by assuming, $u(t)=A\exp(\lambda t)$ and $v(t)=B\exp(\lambda t)$ then using [small perturbation](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Differential_Equations_(Chasnov)/08%3A_Nonlinear_Differential_Equations/8.01%3A_Fixed_Points_and_Stability) we get,

$$
\begin{align}
x(t)&=0+u(t)\\
c(t)&=c_0+v(t)
\end{align}
$$

gives

$$
\begin{cases}
[\lambda+D-K(c_0)]A&=0\\
(\lambda +D)B+\frac1y K(c_0)A&=0
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

eliminating $A$ and $B$ we get the $\lambda=-D$ or $\lambda=K(c_0)-D$. From where, we can say the washout state is stable if $D>K(c_0)$ (because then both $\lambda$ s are negative). But for the normal state,
$$
\begin{align}
x(t)&=\bar x+u(t)\\
c(t)&=\bar c+v(t)
\end{align}
$$
gives,
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{du}{dt}&=[K(c)-D](\bar x + u(t))\\
c(t)&=D[c_0-\bar c - v(t)]-\frac1y K(c)(\bar x + u(t))
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

And again we can let $u(t)=A\exp(\lambda t)$ and $v(t)=B\exp(\lambda t)$. But this time I couldn't see how to get the values for lambdas. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

I was able to get the desire conditions for $(0,c_0)$ point (getting the eigenvalues). My concern was for the second equilibrium point which I called normal state here,$(\bar x+u(t),\bar c+v(t))$ where $u(t),v(t)$ are the perturbation (I'm actually unable to get the linearized system to work with further). In $(1)$ we have found two states, first one $(0,c_0)$ is easy to handle but I was stuck on second one. because we didn't get the explicit point for $x(t)$ and $c(t)$ rather implicit relation $K(\bar c)=D,\bar x=y(c_0-\bar c)$ for $\bar x,\bar c$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. Where did $u,v$ appear from? And what doe they have to do with determining stability?

Comment: I add more context, @copper.hat, please let me know if more context is needed. I was trying to determine condition for which the equilibria are stable (getting condition from $\lambda$ s like for which values $\lambda<0$) to this system using the ansatz $A\exp(\lambda t)$ and $B\exp(\lambda t)$ for $x(t)$ and $c(t)$.

Comment: As far as I can determine (I make mistakes) the eigenvalues of the linearisation about the equilibrium are $K(c_0)-D,-D$. If neither of these are zero you can determine stability from these.

Comment: I was wondering how to write the linearize version of $(2)$, @copper.hat Is it should be $$u'(t)=[K(c)-D]\bar x-Du(t),v'(t)=D[c_0-\bar cv(t)]-\frac1yK(c)\bar x?$$Now inserting ansatz I couldn't get $\lambda$s.

Comment: I don't know how you got those linearised dynamics. I get $u'=(K(c_0)-D)u, v'=-{1 \over y} K(c_0)u - Dv$. I am assuming that you are linearising about $(0,c_0)$. I don't know what you are trying to do with the $\lambda$. Only the eigenvalues matter (assuming the real parts are non zero).

Comment: I was able to get the desire conditions for $(0,c_0)$
 point. My concern was for the second equilibrium point which I called normal state here,$(\bar x+u(t),\bar c+v(t))$ where $u(t),v(t)$ are the perturbation @copper.hat In $(1)$ we have found two states, first one $(0,c_0)$ is easy to handle but I was stuck on second one. because we didn't get the explicit point for $x(t)$ and $c(t)$ rather implicit relation $K(\bar c)=D,\bar x=y(c_0-\bar c)$ for $\bar x,\bar c$.

Comment: I guess I messed up with the context, @copper.hat It will be a great help if you help me with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4802399/1167703) which doesn't need the background of the problem too much. And thank you very much for your responses.